# How to create method like array declaration in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm not sure what the right term for this. I recently try EPPlus to create an excel document. When you want to get a value from cell, you can call a method like this:

```
activeSheet.Cells["A1"].Value;
```

I wonder how to create Cells[string address] method. I try to look at the source, and I got errors. I'm still not understand how to make it. Could you please explain to me about that?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: It is an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/).

Comment: @NickJuelich I got with error code CS0501 " 'SpreadSheetRangeWrapper.this[string].get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial". I'm confused because I don't know the right term of that. I'm searching the right keyword to learn more about it. I'm still new in programming. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you so much @JohnathanBarclay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an "indexer":

```
class WhateverCellsIs
{
    public YourCellType this[string key]
        => GetTheThing(key);
    // ...
}
```